# Linux, bash: Determines the row number of a cell that is in a specific column and has a specific content

Tags: linux, bash, csv

Determines the row number of a cell that is in a specific column and has a specific content.

Remark:

- The heading of a column counts as a line.
- An empty field in a column counts as a row.
- The fields of csv are separated by comma.

Given:

The follow csv file are given:
file.csv

```
    col_o2g,col_dgjdhu,col_of_interest,,
    1234567890,tg75fjksfh,$kj56hahb,,
    dsewsf,1234567890,,,
    khhhdg,5gfj578fj,1234567890,,
           ,57ijf6ehg,46h%sgf,,
    ubthfgfv,zts576fufj,256hf%(",,
```

Given variables:

```
# col variable
col=col_of_interest
# variable with the value of the field of interest
value_of_interest=1234567890
# output variable

# thats he part I am looking for
wanted_line_number=
```

What I have:

```
LINE_CNT=$(awk '-F[\t ]*,[\t ]*' -vcol=${col} '
  FNR==1 {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
         if($i == col) {
             col = i;
             break;
         }
     }
     if(i>NF) {
         exit 1;
     }
 }
 FNR>1 {
     if($col) maxc=FNR;
 }
 END{
     print maxc;
 }' file.csv)
echo line count of lines from column $col  
echo "$LINE_CNT"
```

Wanted output:

```
echo "The wanted line number are:"
echo $wanted_line_number
```

output:4

Comment: What's your field separator? Are there leading spaces or tabs in every row?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail? This is very easy with Awk (hint: `awk -F '\t' '$x==y'` looks whether column `x` contains exactly `y`.)

Comment: @ Cyrus: The fields of csv are seperated by comma.

Comment: @ Cyrus: So far I have no idea how to implement such complicated things for me. So far I am only able to search for pieces of code together, name a little something and combine pieces of code. I need the code piece I am looking for for another query, but for which I have already found a suitable code piece.

Comment: probably you have some "row_of_interest" in your input requirements. Why to print 4?

Comment: @ thanasisp: In this sample, the col of interest have the name "col_of_interest".

Comment: And what is the "specific content" in your description? Why to print `4` as output?

Comment: Because, by my definition, are the value of interest "1234567890" in the 4. Line of the column of interest. Ahh. I see now. I didn define the value of interest. I will add the follow: value_of_interest=1234567890

Comment: It's important to avoid space between @ and username.

Answer (score 1):

```
col="col_of_interest"
value_of_interest="1234567890"

awk -v FS="," -v coi="$col" -v voi="$value_of_interest" \
  'NR==1{
     for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
       if(coi==$i){
         y=i
       }
     }
     next
   }
   {if($y==voi){print NR}}' file
```

Output:

```
4
```

---

See: [GNU awk: String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) (split), [Arrays in awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html), [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/) and `man awk`

Comment: One point for possible improvements: I tryed some variants of possible misinterpreting of search patter. All of tryed variand working fine, only one what misinterpreted. I replaced for testing the "1234567890" by several variants. Only the replacement of "1234567890" by "01234567890" was misinterpreted as "1234567890". I dont know how to fix. All other tested variands are working perfekt.

Comment: For getting the output by variable value, replace the first line by "wanted_line_number=$(awk -v FS="," -v coi="$col" -v voi="$value_of_interest" \" and replace the last line by "{if($y==voi){print NR}}' file.csv)" and add additional the follow line "echo $wanted_line_number"

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to decipher your question, so let me know whether I did it right or not. I guess in your case you don't know how many columns are present in the csv file, and also you don't know whether the first line is the header or not.

For the second remark, I have no automatic solution, so you need to provide whether the line 1 is a header or not based on an input parameter.

Let me show you with a test case

```
]$ more test.csv
col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4
1234567890,tg75fjksfh,kj56hahb,dkdkdkd
dsewsf,1234567890,,dkdkdk
khhhdg,5gfj578fj,1234567890,akdkdkd
ubthfgfv,zts576fufj,256hf,,
```

Then you want to know the position of the column of interest in your csv and also the line where the value of interest is located. Here my example script ( that can be improved ). Keep in mind that I harcoded my example of test.csv file into the script.

```
$ cat check_csv.sh
column_of_interest=$1
value_of_interest=$2
with_header=$3

# check which column is the one

if [[ $with_header = "Y" ]];
then
   num_cols=$(cat test.csv | awk --field-separator="," "{ print NF }" | head -n 1)
   echo "csv contains $num_cols columns"
   to_rows=$(cat test.csv |  head -n 1 | tr ',' '\n')
   iteration=0
   for i in $(cat test.csv |  head -n 1 | tr ',' '\n')
   do
     iteration=$(expr $iteration + 1)
     counter=$(echo $i | egrep -i "$column_of_interest" | wc -l)
     #echo $i
     #echo $counter
     if [ $counter -eq 1 ]
     then
        echo "Column of interest $i is located on number $iteration"
        export my_col_is=$iteration;
    fi
   done
   # fine line that ccontains the value of interest
   iteration=0
   while IFS= read -r line
   do
     iteration=$(expr $iteration + 1 )
     if [[ $iteration -gt 1 ]];
     then
        #echo $line
        is_there=$(echo $line | awk -v temp=$my_col_is -F ',' '{print $temp}' | egrep -i "$value_of_interest"| wc -l)
        #echo $is_there
        if [ $is_there -gt 0 ];
        then
           echo "Value of interest $value_of_interest is present on line $iteration"
        fi
     fi
   done < test.csv
fi
```

Running the example when I want to know which column is col_2 ( position ) and lines where it appears the value 1234567890 for that column. I use an option to identify that the file has header

```
$ more test.csv
col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4
1234567890,tg75fjksfh,kj56hahb,dkdkdkd
dsewsf,1234567890,,dkdkdk
khhhdg,5gfj578fj,1234567890,akdkdkd
ubthfgfv,zts576fufj,256hf,,
$ ./check_csv.sh col_2 1234567890 Y
csv contains 4 columns
Column of interest col_2 is located on number 2
Value of interest 1234567890 is present on line 3
```

With lines duplicated

```
$ more test.csv
col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4
1234567890,tg75fjksfh,kj56hahb,dkdkdkd
dsewsf,1234567890,,dkdkdk
khhhdg,5gfj578fj,1234567890,akdkdkd
ubthfgfv,zts576fufj,256hf,,
dsewsf,1234567890,,dkdkdk
dsewsf,1234567890,,dkdkdk
$ ./check_csv.sh col_2 1234567890 Y
csv contains 4 columns
Column of interest col_2 is located on number 2
Value of interest 1234567890 is present on line 3
Value of interest 1234567890 is present on line 6
Value of interest 1234567890 is present on line 7
$
```

If you want to treat the files without header, you only need to copy the code to the treat those without `head -1`, but in those cases, you cannot get names of the columns and you won't know where to find them respect of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
file=./input.csv
d=,

# get column number for col_of_interest
c=$(head -n1 "$file" | grep -oE "[^$d]+" | grep -niw "$col" | cut -d: -f1)

# print column with cut and get line numbers for 1234567890
[ "$c" -gt 0 ] && wanted_line_number=$(cut -d$d -f$c "$file" | grep -niw "$value_of_interest" | cut -d: -f1)
printf "The wanted line number are: %b\n" $wanted_line_number
```

Comment: `[^,]+` will match any string (`,` excluded), `cut -d, -f3 file.csv` will use delimiter `,` and print only field `3`, `grep -n` will print line numbers